# Only run GitHub Actions manually while blocking Pull Request

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a set of GitHub Actions configured to block pull requests from being merged until the Actions complete successfully. However, every time a new commit is pushed to a PR, the Actions are run again, which can be very wasteful if the author is not yet ready to merge, and intends to make future changes. Is there any way to have a GitHub Action still block a PR being merged but also not run the Action automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [this recent update](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-04-08-convert-pull-request-to-draft/) you can now convert pull requests back to draft status. So you could do that when you need to make changes and disable the CI for drafts. Then convert the draft to a pull request after the changes are complete to rerun CI.

```
on: pull_request
jobs:
  build:
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == false
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      ...
```

Comment: Take care, there is a typo. It should be `false` without the single quotes. 

Moreover, you have to get access to the correct types of pull request, as shown in the example there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68349031/only-run-actions-on-non-draft-pull-request

Comment: @JMMontanier I'm fairly sure that this used to work because originally GitHub Actions had no boolean types, only strings. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One workaroound would be for the Action to look for a specific comment (for example: "`[TO MERGE]: this commit is about ...`), and:

- return immediately if '`[TO MERGE]`' is not found, minimizing the action overhead on each commit
- go on with checks, if '`[TO MERGE]`' is found.