# Perform Github Action when trying to merge branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm setting up Github actions for a few of my projects.
The flow I'd like to achieve is:

1. A developer clicks on the "Merge pull request" button
2. A Github action testing workflow will take place
3. If the tests pass - The merge is executed

The reason for this kind of flow, is I wouldn't like the tests to run on each commit pushed to the branch. I want the flow to run only when trying to merge.

My question is:
***Is there a way to manually execute a workflow only when trying / wanting to merge, and making sure the branch can be merged into master if and only if the tests have passed?***

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61788540/only-run-github-actions-manually-while-blocking-pull-request/61791582#61791582) where you can disable your CI for drafts and convert to a pull request when you want to run the CI and merge.

Comment: @peterevans good point! Does this require devs to be disciplined and use draft PRs until they're ready to merge? Or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: You can convert a pull request to a draft now, too. So it’s easy to switch back and forth, until ready to merge.

Comment: Right! But the burden is still on the individual devs to do the right thing, correct? I believe OP is ultimately looking for a solution which doesn't rely on that.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Another option would be a pull request [slash command](https://github.com/peter-evans/slash-command-dispatch) to run tests manually.

Answer (score 11):

## UPDATE 2023-03-08

Github now has merge queues in beta, [which allow you to trigger a workflow when a PR is added to a merge group](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/managing-a-merge-queue#triggering-merge-group-checks-with-github-actions). Using that functionality you should be able to trigger a workflow when the PR is added to the merge queue. You can also specify that the merge should fail if the tests fail.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is currently only a solution for repositories of organizations.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there's no `merged` or `merge_attempt` activity type on the [pull request event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) (yet). Even if there was, I don't believe GitHub has a way to block merges on the completion of a workflow (yet).

What I would suggest as a workaround here is to run your test 1. after the fact on pushes to the `master` branch, and 2. on `pull_request` events with certain activity types which indicate that the user is likely to attempt a merge soon. For example, `ready_for_review` or `review_requested`.

Something like this:

```
name: tests
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
    types: 
      - ready_for_review
      - review_requested
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a useful approach until the checks triggered via `workflow_dispatch` (manual) update their Status Checks.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to trigger an action when there was no changes in current branch/pull-request, but in base branch. But we need to trigger the check again when base branch changes (e.g. we want to ensure current branch is rebased on top of latest master). The only way is to turn on checkbox "Require branches to be up to date before merging", but that would add a button to merge changes from base branch to current branch (we want rebase instead). So it seems there's no way to do that :(