# How to stop GitHub actions starting if a GitHub check has failed?

Tags: github, github-actions

Currently, our team has limited GitHub actions in minutes, so I would only like to run GitHub actions when the WIP flag is not present.

Currently we use this plugin [WIP](https://github.com/marketplace/wip) to check if a branch is work in progress.

Is there a way that if the commit is flagged as WIP, that the GitHub actions to not trigger so we can conserve our monthly minutes allowance?

Comment: If you are open to an alternative to the WIP plugin, you could use pull request drafts and filter your CI workflows based on if it's in draft status or not. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61791582/11934042)

Comment: Does WIP append WIP to the Pr title, or something?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `pull_request` event with the `ready_for_review` or even `review_requested` tags.

This example will only run when a pull request is marked ready for review.

```yaml
on:
    pull_request:
        types: [ready_for_review]
```

- [Draft pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests#draft-pull-requests)
- [Pull request trigger event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request)