# Only run actions on non draft pull request

Tags: github-actions, pull-request

I have set Github actions to be skipped when a draft pull request has been created however it is not trigger when the pull request is ready for review. Is there any way to run the action when I draft PR is changed from draft to ready for review?

```
pull_request:
  types: ['opened', 'edited', 'reopened', 'synchronize', 'ready_for_review']

jobs:
 build:
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == 'false'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

Comment: Changing `github.event.pull_request.draft == 'false'` to `github.event.pull_request.draft == false` makes it work.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`pull_request.draft` is a boolean, but you're treating it as a string, so the types in your comparison don't match.

According to the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators), the operands are coerced to numbers in this case: the left-hand side (boolean) becomes `1` if true and `0` if false; the right-hand side (string) becomes `NaN`, so your `if` statement will never evaluate to `true`.

To fix, drop the quotes:

```yaml
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == false
```

This can be shortened using the negation operator `!`, but because `!` is special for YAML, the value has to be quoted:

```yaml
    if: '! github.event.pull_request.draft'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if: github.event.pull_request.draft == false
```

This answer by Benjamin is 100% correct. However, there are drawbacks explained in https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25722 , so I see a fellow developer

```
types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, ready_for_review]

jobs:
  fail_if_pull_request_is_draft:
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == true
    runs-on: ...
    steps:
        run: exit 1

  get_changes:
    runs-on: ...
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == false
```