# Github Actions: Running a workflow on non-draft PRs

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I have workflow file that I want it to run on non-draft PRs and on every new commit to the PR.

So far, I have tried two ways:

1. Using if statement

```yaml
name: Test

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  test:
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == false
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

This does not trigger workflow when PR converted to ready for review.

2. Using types statement

```yaml
name: Test

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
    types:
      - ready_for_review

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

This does not trigger workflow when a new commit pushed to PR.

How can I add a condition so that my workflow runs on non-draft PRs and also all new commits?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only run actions on non draft pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68349031/only-run-actions-on-non-draft-pull-request)

Answer (score 7):

In your first code block you leave the `types` as the default (`opened`, `synchronize` & `reopened`).
In the second code block you only use the `ready_for_review` type.

You can just combine the two:

```
name: Test

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - reopened
      - ready_for_review

jobs:
  test:
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == false
    # You could have ths version too - note the  single quotes:
    # if: '! github.event.pull_request.draft'
    name: Check PR is not a Draft
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "Non-draft Pull request change detected"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68349031/only-run-actions-on-non-draft-pull-request).

The answer in the other question suggests using

```yaml
if: ! github.event.pull_request.draft
```

to check if the PR is a draft, since there might otherwise be some type confusion with booleans in GitHub Actions.

Comment: no, this is not duplicate of another question, since my provided statement also works well. However, it does not cover when PR type changed to READY_FOR_REVIEW. I tested with opening a non-draft PR and converting another PR from draft to ready for review.

Comment: Okay, sorry. I see that it is not a duplicate. Let me edit my answer